# Add Botan library to CLion C++ project

Tags: c++, cmake, cryptography, clion, botan

I have been trying to add the [Botan](https://botan.randombit.net/) library to my C++ project but I haven't figured it out yet. I am on Ubuntu 22.04 using CLion with CMake.

I downloaded the latest (3.3.0) release from [GitHub](https://github.com/randombit/botan) and followed the [documentation](https://botan.randombit.net/handbook/building.html) on building the library. I ran these commands on my system which installed the library successfully:

```
$ ./configure.py
$ make
$ make check
$ make install
```

When I created a new project in CLion named `example`, I added the following to my CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.27)
project(example)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

add_executable(example main.cpp)

find_package(Botan 3.3.0)
find_package(Botan 3.3.0 COMPONENTS rsa ecdsa tls13)
find_package(Botan 3.3.0 OPTIONAL_COMPONENTS tls13_pqc)
include_directories("/usr/include")
target_link_libraries(example "Downloads/Botan-3.3.0/libbotan-3.so")
```

I created a file called `main.cpp` in which I added the [RSA code example](https://botan.randombit.net/handbook/api_ref/pubkey.html#rsa-example) from the documentation:

```
#include <botan/auto_rng.h>
#include <botan/hex.h>
#include <botan/pk_keys.h>
#include <botan/pkcs8.h>
#include <botan/pubkey.h>
#include <botan/rng.h>

#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
   if(argc != 2) {
      return 1;
   }
   std::string plaintext(
      "Your great-grandfather gave this watch to your granddad for good luck. "
      "Unfortunately, Dane's luck wasn't as good as his old man's.");
   std::vector<uint8_t> pt(plaintext.data(), plaintext.data() + plaintext.length());
   Botan::AutoSeeded_RNG rng;

   // load keypair
   Botan::DataSource_Stream in(argv[1]);
   auto kp = Botan::PKCS8::load_key(in);

   // encrypt with pk
   Botan::PK_Encryptor_EME enc(*kp, rng, "OAEP(SHA-256)");
   std::vector<uint8_t> ct = enc.encrypt(pt, rng);

   // decrypt with sk
   Botan::PK_Decryptor_EME dec(*kp, rng, "OAEP(SHA-256)");
   Botan::secure_vector<uint8_t> pt2 = dec.decrypt(ct);

   std::cout << "\nenc: " << Botan::hex_encode(ct) << "\ndec: " << Botan::hex_encode(pt2);

   return 0;
}
```

But when I try to build my project, I get the following error:

```
fatal error: botan/auto_rng.h: No such file or directory
    1 | #include <botan/auto_rng.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

I have tried some solutions online (although I found that most people are using Botan with Visual Studio on Windows) which require changing my `CMakeLists.txt` many times and checking for case sensitivity but nothing has worked.

Comment: `include_directories("/usr/include")` makes no sense. This directory is already in system include paths. Delete it.

Comment: `target_link_libraries(example "Downloads/Botan-3.3.0/libbotan-3.so")` is wrong. Must be `target_link_libraries(example PRIVATE Botan::Botan)`

Comment: Remove 3 calls to `find_package`. Just `find_package(Botan REQUIRED)` is fine.

Comment: So, I changed it to only contain `find_package(Botan 3.3.0)`, 
`target_link_libraries(example PRIVATE Botan::Botan)` and although I don't get any more errors like previously I get: `error: ‘ranges’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a type
   51 | template <typename T, typename ValueT = std::ranges::range_value_t<T>>`

Comment: `std::ranges` is from C++20; you specified C++ 17.

Comment: @Botje You are correct, everything works now. Such a silly mistake from me.